# Compiling C++ file with CMAKE (Unrecognized '-rdynamic')

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, arm

I am trying to add a single C++ file to a working CMAKE project.

The project is building fine when I only have C files in the project.  However, as soon as I add a cpp file to the `ADD_EXECUTABLE` section of `CMakeLists.txt` I get the following error: `arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? Or what I could do to fix it?

Thanks so much for the help!

PS - I have a section at the top of the `CMakeLists.txt` that says `SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS) # get rid of -rdynamic`, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Did you try to googling for this error message? Also, is compiler `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is used for cross-compiling? If so, problem could be that your toolchain file doesn't provide all needed information for CMake.

Comment: Yes I tried googling the message, and didn't find anything useful.  And yes the compiler can cross-compile.  Everything works fine until I include a cpp file.

Comment: Then give us more info about your environment and code: Is this is Linux or MinGW? `CMakeLists.txt` **in the simplest form** ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), toolchain file.

Answer (score -1):

Check the armgcc.cmake (or equivalent). I found a field there named CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME and CMAKE_SYSTEM.  These need to be renamed to 'Generic'.  This took care of the problem for me.